# How do I get jscrollpane to co-exist with a jquery accordion script?

Tags: accordion, conflict, jscrollpane

I have a site that uses a accordion script, and I want to place a scrollbox inside one of the accordion tabs. However, the scrollbox works just fine, but breaks the accordion script. Is there a way around this conflict?

This is the site with just the accordion script:
http://www.namibiaonline.net/sandbox/NBAA/index9.html

And this is the broken one with jscrollpane and the accordion script:
(for some reason I'm only allowed to paste one hyperlink, so to get to the broken one, just replace /index9.html with /scroll_test.html)

Any help would be much appreciated :)
Ash

Comment: http://www.namibiaonline.net/sandbox/NBAA/scroll_test.html

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. Try the beta:

http://groups.google.com/group/jscrollpane/browse_thread/thread/c1bc1bf63e3f80d8

and I believe this is where your issue lied:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/auto_reinitialise.html

Comment: That is the version of jscrollpane I'm using and auto reinitialize doesn't seem to make a difference (unless I'm inserting that code in the wrong place). So far the best results I've had so far was from removing

<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode"> 
 $(function()
 {
  $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
 });
</script>

and then it works, except when I click on another tab and then back to the tab with the scrollbox in it, the scrollbar is gone :-/

Comment: Try using a callback to reinitialize the scrollpane each time you cahnge.

Comment: I think you're onto something there, that code does what I want, though it uses tabs that it generates, I suppose I should just figure out how to do that to my existing tabs. I'm a designer, so my scripting abilities are rather limited, but thanks, I'm much closer to a solution now than I ever was :)

Comment: I've also noticed that the scroll bar (when its working before one of the accordion tabs are clicked) isn't styled, its just a regular scroll bar. I built it on its own in a new file and linked to the same .css and .js files and it works, but not with the accordion script :-/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I almost solved it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
scrollPane = jQuery(".scroll-pane").jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true
    });
var api = scrollPane.data('jsp');


jQuery("#accordion").accordion({
            changestart: function(event, ui) {               
                api.reinitialise()                  
            }
        });
}
```

Be sure that you define the correct width height for the containers which have the scroll-pane class. In my case I have created 3 containers like this:

```
<div class="scroll-pane">

.scroll-pane { 
overflow: auto;
height: 134px; 
width: 420px;
```

}

The class scroll-pane is where I defined the overflow, height and width. If I do in the parent container, the scroll is not shown because it takes all the height and also if I do in a child container, a non stylized scroll is shown.

But I still having an issue with the first pane. It is correctly shown the first time the page is loaded, but when I move to another accordion tab and then come back to the first one, the width of this element is set to 0. It only happens with the first one the others work fine.